# How can I make slide photo full size for phones?

Tags: html, image, slider, responsive

How can i make slide photo full size for phones ?

Here have i link of my website: [Ekizceliler](http://www.ekizceliler.com/)

if you watch it website with phone then see you the slide picture very huge, how can i make the slide picture in good size?

Answer (score 0):

to make a responsive slider , in your css make the main div

```
width : 100vw; 
height : 50vh ; 
/* you can change height as you want */
background : cover ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="flexslider top_slider" style="height:32vh;width:100%">
```

this might give you a temporary solution, but due to accesibility, I would recommend you to:

1. Use a slider for an entertainment value, so avoid text in it
2. Maybe it is a better idea, to use a media query to hide the slider on mobile devices, because even if you manage to resize them, you will always lose a lot of quality, and in the end, texts are so small, you can't read them anymore.  If those pictures are required for your purposes, try to put them on a page, that way your visitors will pay more attention to them.